# Why does vuze (bittorrent client) discard some of my downloads?

Tags: bittorrent

I am using the vuze bittorrent client (to *legally* download files, such as linux iso files) and there's always a few kb that are discarded:

[image]

What's this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main reasons for the existence of discarded (aka *wasted*) data on *any* torrent client: Hash fails (aka *bad data*) and discarded data.

- Every .torrent file contains a hash, that allows the client to verify the integrity of the packages it receives. If any package fails the hashing process, it is therefore discarded. If the client added that data to the files you were downloading, most likely you would get a corrupted file.

  This kind of procedure reduces the probability of corruption, although it is possible (but unlikely) that it happens. This is called *hash collision* (because two unrelated packages can have the same hash, if the hash isn't [resistant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistant)). As .torrent files generally use 160 bit hashes they are reasonably free form collision <sup>[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_BitTorrent_terms#Hash)</sup>.
- Discarded data itself is data that's sent to you by a peer that your client didn't want <sup>[source](http://www.utorrent.com/intl/en/help/faq#faq9)</sup>. As I also supposed previously, connection, peer, handshake, and any other kind of data transfered between clients that is not a file but is related to the file's transfer might be added to this total <sup>source needed</sup>.